# How do I filter CollectionGroup Query with 'where' in Flutter Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I Have a CollectionGroup query which displays all document data from 'school_news' collection in a Listtile with Streambuilder and ListView.

But now I want to only show the document data in a ListView/Listtile where 'name' field equals name in a list , like :

```
List userSelections = ['Liebenberg', 'St Michaels' , 'School C' ];


FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collectionGroup('school_news')
    .where('name', arrayContainsAny: userSelections )
    .snapshots(),
```

So what I want now is to only then display the document data fields  in a ListView/Listtile where the 'name' fields are Liebenberg, St Michaels and  'School C' instead of all the document data in 'school_news' collection .

Is something like that possible ? I tried with the code above but with no luck, So I am not sure what I'm missing .

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated .Thank you

**UPDATE**

I have updated as per answer and included full code , as below :

```
class UserHome extends StatefulWidget {
  const UserHome({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _UserHomeState createState() => _UserHomeState();
}

class _UserHomeState extends State<UserHome> {
  final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
  final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  List userSelections = ['Liebenberg', 'St Michaels'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collectionGroup('school_news')
            .where('name', whereIn: userSelections)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(
              child: Text('Loading '),
            );
          } else
            return ListView(
              children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((doc) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {},
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        ListTile(
                          leading: Text(doc['title']),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }).toList(),
            );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Firestore BD / Collection Path]

Seems like no data is returned  as the page just displays 'Loading'  .
The link for creating the new index for the 'WhereIn' I also dont get .

Anything I am doin wrong ?

Thanks for the help so far  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `whereIn` instead of `arrayContainsAny`.
replace this line

```
.where('name', arrayContainsAny: userSelections )
```

with this one:

```
.where('name', whereIn: userSelections)
```

Remember that Firestore has a built-in constraint where you can't have more than 10 items in your list. It means your list `userSelections` cannot have more than 10 values (otherwise you may want to do the filter client side, depending on your use case)

Also, in your 1st execution, you may need to add a new index... just follow the web link (in the new error message) that will help create this required index directly in Firestore.

Comment: *otherwise you may want to do the filter client-side* That's not necessary. You can perform multiple `whereIn` queries, each time using new (10) elements.

Comment: I updated my code as per answer . Please see , as it seems no data is returned . Thanks for help so far

Comment: Do you get any error message? error message helps. Can you show a snapshot from a Document from Firestore (just to confirm you are not doing something wrong).

Comment: Dont worry about the 'index' part, when your code will work, you will get an error message explaining exactly what you need to do (lets forget about this for now)

Comment: The CollectionGroup query works without the 'where' statement . What I also noticed was if I play around with the 'where' statements ( example  where('group',isEqualTo: 'Grade 3') ) . Then I get data which is displayed for like 1 second , then it goes back to 'loading' again . The only message i get from Debug Consol is 'Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)'

Comment: Strange , I added a 'orderBy' with criteria and it worked after that : StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: db
            .collectionGroup('school_news')
            .where('name', whereIn: userSelections)
            .orderBy('created', descending: true)
            .snapshots(),

Comment: Cool ;0) So is the issue fixed now? Don't forget to accept the answer as it answered your original question (whereIn).